# sdo_geom.relate determines DISJOINT where CONTAINS expected

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

I get the following behaviour on 10.2.0.5 (win64) and 11.2.0.3 patch 7 (win32).

I'm not sure if my expectations are wrong or Oracle's results.

When creating a buffer around a line element and determining the relation between the buffer and the line I expect to get CONTAINS (the line is contained within the boundaries of the buffer) but I get DISJOINT.

Here is the test code:

```
declare
   l_geo1   mdsys.sdo_geometry;
   l_geo2   mdsys.sdo_geometry;
   l_relate varchar2(100);
begin

   -- Create the line
   l_geo1 := mdsys.sdo_geometry(2002
                               ,90112
                               ,null
                               ,mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1)
                               ,mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(153972.952, 473287.52, 153972.839, 473281.531));

   -- Create the buffer using 0.020 meters = 20mm

   l_geo2 := sdo_geom.sdo_buffer(l_geo1, 0.020, 0.0005);

   -- Determine the relation
   l_relate := sdo_geom.relate(l_geo2, 'determine', l_geo1, 0.0005);

   dbms_output.put_line(l_relate);

end;
```

When using buffer size 0 the relation is EQUAL (as expected).
When using buffer sizes 0.01-0.26 the relation is DISJOINT
When using buffer size > 0.027 the relation is CONTAINS.

This behaviour is found in quite a few lines in our dataset. All these lines run in an almost north-south direction.

Are my expectations about the outcome correct?
Is the sdo_geom.relate function returning the wrong result?

thanks, Rene.

Edit: Added a loop for different buffer sizes:

```
0 EQUAL
.001 CONTAINS
.002 CONTAINS
.003 CONTAINS
.004 CONTAINS
.005 CONTAINS
.006 DISJOINT
.007 DISJOINT
.008 DISJOINT
.009 DISJOINT
.01 DISJOINT
.011 DISJOINT
.012 DISJOINT
.013 DISJOINT
.014 DISJOINT
.015 DISJOINT
.016 DISJOINT
.017 DISJOINT
.018 DISJOINT
.019 DISJOINT
.02 DISJOINT
.021 DISJOINT
.022 DISJOINT
.023 DISJOINT
.024 DISJOINT
.025 DISJOINT
.026 DISJOINT
.027 CONTAINS
.028 CONTAINS
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that sdo_geom.relate is returning the wrong result (the results all look fine and sensible on MapViewer).

However, it's worth noting that if you perform the relate DETERMINE with a tolerance of 0.0001, it returns CONTAINS for all of your above cases (0.001 to 0.028) as you'd expect.

Although I haven't looked into it any further, you may find that the buffering results are (for some reason) within your tolerance between 0.006 and 0.026. There have been some issues with the in-built buffering command in the past, so it wouldn't surprise me if it wasn't completely consistent.